# Ajax. При вызове данных по ключу из словаря получаю undefined

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Имеется функция ajax, принимающая данные с формы и отправляющая их на сервер django в представление. В представлении производится проверка логина и пароля, если пользователь успешно залогинен, то возвращается словарь с ключами signupstatus (численное значение 1) и trash (со строковым значением trash). Ajax ф-ция получает данные в виде словаря. Так при вызове `console.log(data)` я получаю **{"signupstatus":1, "trash":"trash"}**. Плавно переходя к основной проблеме: при вызове `console.log(data.signupstatus)` я получаю данные типа **unidentified**. В чём же кроется проблема? (на мой взгляд что-то с названиями ключей)

Код ajax-функции:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('#signin_form');
    form.on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = form.attr("action");
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var csrf_token = $('#signin_form [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
        console.log(username);
        console.log(password);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {
                'username': username,
                'password': password,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token,
            },
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.signupstatus);
                console.log(data.trash);
                if(data.signup){
                    console.log('lol')
                }
            }
        })
    })  
})
```

Представление на Django:

```
def sigin(request):
return_dict = dict()
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return_dict["signupstatus"] = 1
        return_dict["trash"] = 'trash'
    else:
        return_dict["signupstatus"] = 0
return JsonResponse(return_dict)
```

Заранее прошу не предлагать использовать предустановленные формы для логина и прочих фич от django (хочется самому разобраться с аутентификацией, чтобы лучше проникнуться фреймворком). Заранее благодарю за ваши ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(typeof data); // string?
```

Измените:

```
dataType: "text",
```

нa

```
dataType: "json",
```

`data` станет не строкой, а объектом со всеми свойствами из словаря.

Comment: Благодарю! Не думал, что возвращаемый тип данных тоже примет строковое значение.

Comment: @chattingtoofast На здоровье. Успехов! На аккуратно заданный вопрос приятно отвечать. `dataType` - это как раз тип данных ответа.